# awk read and split headers from one file, use it on other files

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm using an awk script which takes the column headers after 166th column and prints it into each of it's subsequent rows.

Ex.

```
col165    col166    col167
a         1         2
b         3         4
c         5         6
```

Becomes -

```
col165    col166    col167
a         col166|1         col167|2
b         col166|3         col167|4
c         col166|5         col167|6
```

However, the file which I'm processing is quite huge (around 1.6M lines) which takes about 1.5 hours to process.

To speed up the process, I thought of splitting the huge file into 100k lines, then use gnu `parallel` to process each file separately. I've run into a problem however, the script takes the header of the file and uses that to obtain the headers. I wanted to use another file just to specify the headers, else I would have to add headers to each of the split files (which seems like a hassle in of itself).

The code which I'm using is -

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t";OFS="\t" };
     NR == 1 { split($0, headers); print; next }
     {for (i=166;i<=NF;i++) $i=headers[i] "|" $i } 1' input > output
```

I wanted to use a file `column_headers` to specify the headers. Would it be possible?

I tried the following code but it didn't work and I'm not sure if my code is  correct:

```
awk -v head='$(cat column_headers)' 'BEGIN{ FS="\t";OFS="\t" };
        NR == 1 { split($head, headers); print; next }
        {for (i=166;i<=NF;i++) $i=headers[i] "|" $i } 1' input > output
```

I think I'm doing something wrong, not sure what. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks. I had missed out another command in the chain, which was actually the culprit for long times.

As @Ole Tange mentioned, I used the command though modified it slightly -

```
time cat input_1|parallel -k -q -j 24 --tmpdir tmp/ --block 900M --pipe awk -f culprit_script > output
```

The script basically splits each field, and removes/retains them based on their value.

The execution time of the first command is around 15-20 min, the second script takes little more than an hour. With parallel and 24 threads, it gets over in 7 minutes!! I think I'll use parallel for first command too :P

Thanks for the input everyone!

Comment: Welcome to the site. You are using the `-v` option to pass a variable to `awk`, but the variable value is inside single quotes which disables any substitution, including command substitution. Can you try `-v head="$(cat column_headers)"` with double-quotes instead?

Comment: The `split($head, headers);` has an unwanted `$`. Awk variables are not prefixed with $ unless they are fields.

Comment: It's hard to believe that an awk script could take 1.5 hours to process a file that's just 1.6 million lines long (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/603157/133219). How many columns does each row of your file have? Are you maybe calling awk repeatedly in a shell loop or similar so it's not executing the awk script that's slow it's something else you're doing around it?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but too big and requires formatting so it can't be a comment so...

1.6M is not a huge number of lines. 1 million lines per hour as you say you're seeing is **massively** slow, 1 million lines per minute would be more in the ballpark of reasonable. For example, I created a file that's 1,600,000 lines long, each with 300 columns by running this script:

```
$ awk -v n=1600000 -v c=300 -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN{for (j=1;j<=c;j++) printf "col%s%s",j,(j<c?OFS:ORS); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) for (j=1;j<=c;j++) printf "%s%s",j,(j<c?OFS:ORS)}' > file
```

and then I timed running a script to do the conversion in your question on that file:

```
$ time awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==1{split($0, headers); print; next} {for (i=166;i<=NF;i++) $i=headers[i] "|" $i } 1' file > out

real    1m22.569s
user    1m17.971s
sys     0m4.359s
```

So that took about 82 seconds instead of 1.5 hours to run.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it looks a bit like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

do_block() {
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     NR==1{split($0, headers); next}
     {for (i=166;i<=NF;i++) $i=headers[i] "|" $i } 1'
}
export -f do_block

# Non-parallel version
cat file | head -n1 > out1
time cat file | do_block >> out1

# Parallel version
cat file | head -n1 > out2
time parallel -k --pipepart --block -30 -a file --header : do_block >> out2
```

On my 4 core CPU the parallel version is around 3 times faster.